# Validity Fingerprint Sensor not detected

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, sensors, fingerprint-reader

I have a VFS471 Validity Fingerprint driver that is not detected in my HP Probook 4530s. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is for validity fingerprint reader VF3000 found in Dell Vostro series laptops but might help you. http://www.tuxtrix.com/2012/05/how-to-activate-validity-fingerprint.html

Steps from above link

1. Before you install this, please remove the fingerprint-gui ppa

   ```
   sudo ppa-purge  ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
   ```
2. This has only been tested on amd64 system. We are awaiting packages for 32bit systems
3. The program is still under development, so expect a few crashes and error reports

   To install the driver for the fingerprint reader, follow the instructions below:

   1. Add this PPA to your sources:

      ```
      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get upgrade
      ```
   2. Download the libfprint package and Install the software packages:

      ```
       sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd gksu-polkit
       sudo dpkg -i libfprint0_0.4.0+git20120202-0ppa1~precise2_amd64.deb`
      ```
   3. Log out and then log back in
   4. Open "Users and Accounts" and then click fingerprint to register your fingerprint. See the screenshots below on how to register your fingerprint.

The main launchpad page for this project is [here](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fingerprint-gui)

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: @Fabby: It's my blog. So it will stay there :) . BUt your point is valid. I'm adding the steps.

Comment: And upvoted!  **;-)** And edited!  **>:)**