# installing fingerprint scanner on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: hp, fingerprint-reader

How do I get my fingerprint scanner to work on HP ProBook 4530s, Ubuntu 15.10? Where do I find it, how do I install it?
My reader is 1d6b:0003 
tnx a lot

Comment: ok got the reader wrong...reader is ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/726825/edit) your question and add the above details. And see http://askubuntu.com/questions/182242/validity-fingerprint-sensor-not-detected

Answer (score 0):

This fingerprint reader is not supported in Linux, Validity did release the source code or a binary for this fingerprint reader model. At this age Validity will likely never release it, but you can sign the petition request to biometric manufacturers to release open source code for readers [here](https://www.change.org/p/biometric-devices-manufactures-opensource-drivers-for-fingerprint-scanners-and-or-release-documentation-needed-to-write-such-drivers) but there is little support for it.