# Validity Fingerprint Scanner VFS491 not working

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I have an HP Probook 4545s and it came with a Validity Fingerprint scanner. However, when I installed ubuntu I realized that the fingerprint scanner ceased to work. After some sleuthing, I found this post: [Validity Fingerprint Sensor not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182242/validity-fingerprint-sensor-not-detected) ;however, it did not solve my problem. What can I do to get the driver installed so that I may use the fingerprint scanner?

Answer (score 0):

I use fingerprint-gui on my Thinkpad, but I don't know if it will work for you. Here's the Launchpad page: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui

Comment: Thank you for the link however my fingerprint reader ID is 138a:003d, which is not listed unfortunately. I appreciate the suggestion though.